# Unable to load data in express server which is coming from front end

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Whenever I send data from front end data is going to the back-end but I'm receiving empty object in body. I user body parser also but I'm getting same error. Below is my server code.

Error

```
Error! 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/sms", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token Y in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "You sent: undefined to Express"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/sms"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/sms"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
const bodyparser=require("body-parser");
const cors=require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.post('/sms', function (req, res) {
    const body = req.body.Body
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.send(`You sent: ${body} to Express`)
  })




app.get("/",(req,res) =>{
    res.send("We are in home");;

})

app.post("/users",(req,res) =>{
  console.log(req.body);

})



app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

this too
// parse application/json

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your code.

```
const express = require("express");
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyparser.json())

app.post('/sms', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    const body = req.body
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.send(`You sent: ${body} to Express`)
})




app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("We are in home");;

})

app.post("/users", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({ success: true })
})



app.listen(8080);
```

Try this. I've modified a couple of lines

Comment: Hi Prashanth, Thankyou for your help i updated this code but still i'm getting same error.

Comment: What is your request url & body?

Comment: I added "responseType : 'text'" in headers problem is resolved